# Help with a Series convergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^n} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$$
I've no clue how to even being to solve this one, but the end result is $\frac{e}{e-1}$.
Help would be great. This *is* a homework problem, but it's not for a grade. It's for practice.

Thanks again!

Comment: Consider the two summands separately. Each on its own is easy to see the good test for.

Comment: The sum must be, at least, from $\;n=2\;$ ...

Comment: As it stands, your series is ill-defined. Is it perhaps supposed to be $n(n+1)$ in the denominator? That would fix things.

Comment: Ah! i put the denominator incorrectly, I Fixed it! thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm sure the answers will be corrected to accommodate the change shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sum \frac1{e^n}$ is a geometric series with ratio $e^{-1}$, so you may handle it with
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{e^n} = \frac{\text{first term}}{1-\text{common ratio}} = \frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1}}.
$$
As for the second sum, note that
$$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$
so the series telescopes.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

If $\;|q|<1\;$ , then

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty q^n=\frac{q^k}{1-q}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^M\frac1{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^M\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac1M-\frac1{M+1}\right)$$